# What are the differences among Inheritance, Delegation, Category and Observer Pattern in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, design-patterns, delegation

I'm new to Objective-C and so am to iOS. I've been developing Android apps - and therefore pretty comfortable with using Inheritance. But in iOS, almost everything is implemented using Delegation. So basically my question is:

- What is the difference between these four concepts and when to use each? What are the pros and cons of using each?

I searched this question on Stackoverflow, but on no place, I could find those concepts together.

Comment: You question is too broad to formulate an answer. I can only point you to few resources: [iOS Design Patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns), [Cocoa Fundamentals guide](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6)

Comment: These are a bunch of unrelated things. You're basically asking us to rewrite the documentation for a large part of the language. You'd be better off just reading the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inheritance :**

Way by which you inherit property of base class to subclass. All public and protected members are inherited to subclass. *Obj-C doesn't have private members so this is not into play.(However you create them by class extensions, even there is some hack to access it).

**Delegation :**

Way by which you delegate the task of one class to another. The frequent used class and delegates are of `UITableViewDelegate`. This is always 1-to-1. Callback and return value can be used.

**Category :**

Way by which you add new methods to an Existing class. When you do this, subclass are also able to use the categorized methods. You never add property using category. *However you can  add using associated objects.

**Observer Pattern :**

A class acts as a broadcaster and broadcasts a message. It doesn't care about who other are its observer or recipient. And all observers receives the notification sent by the observer and start performing on that message. This can be 1-to-0, 1-to-1 or 1-to-many. Even more than one broadcaster can send same notifications hence you can say *-to-*. Here no call back or return value is sent.

Comment: So the only difference between Delegation and Observer Pattern is "return value is sent"?

Comment: In delegates it may return a value while in observer it can't. Also there may not be any observer even your program runs well but in case of delegate the delegate must be present otherwise it will crash!!!

Comment: It is not true that, for any class that uses a delegate, the delegate must always be present or the program will crash. In fact, that sounds like pretty poor behavior to me.